# iOS Swift: NSMutableString vs [Character] which is better for known size?

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm, memory-management

I'm doing some text processing, involving converting a number of characters into strings. Input is a long sequence of `Character` and output is a number of strings created from the `Character` sequence based on certain rules.

Say:

```swift
let input = "The quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog."
```

I wonder which one of the following is more efficient:

```swift
let buffer = NSMutableString(capacity: MAX_SIZE)
var result = [String]()
for c in input {
    buffer.append(String(c))
    if (isComplete(buffer)) {
        result.append(String(buffer))
        buffer.deleteCharacters(in: NSRange(location: 0, length: buffer.length))
    }
}
```

vs:

```swift
var buffer = [Character]()
var result = [String]()
for c in input {
    buffer.append(c)
    if (isComplete(buffer)) {
        result.append(String(buffer))
        buffer.removeAll()
    }
}
```

It looks to me the second approach is better because it doesn't have to convert each character into a `String` for storing in `NSMutableString`, but because we know the maximum possible buffer size, the first approach has specified the `capacity` for the mutable string, which *may* be better in term of memory management ie. memory re-allocation when adding more characters that are beyond allocated memory space for buffer?

Thanks!

Comment: I strongly suspect that unless you are dealing with million+ character strings it doesn't matter. The second code looks simpler and is easier to understand so I would use that. In general, in Swift you don't use `NS` classes if you can avoid it

Comment: Character is deprecated in Swift.

Comment: @AnkurLahiry `Character` is definitely not deprecated.  The `characters` property on `String`, however, is deprecated.

Comment: @hzxu You can call `reserveCapacity` on `Array`, or for that matter, on `String`, to eliminate reallocation overhead, and pass `keepingCapacity: true` in your call to `removeAll`

Comment: Now sure what "processing" you need but as others have already mentioned you should work with Swift native lives like String. Btw result should be an Array of Substrings IMO

Answer (score -1):

We have to understand the NSMutableString gives a more controlled wrapper to manipulate characters. Can work with multiple strings.

[Character] is like traditional array and works same. More manual work and all limitation of an array.